# What Does PHP $_GET return when not passed a value?

Tags: php

What would variable `$_GET['name']` if the value was not passed in the url?
I googled it but could not come up with anything.

Comment: i did not because this is my second day using php and i don't know that much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It returns `null`:

```
if (!isset($_GET['foo'])) echo "foo was null";
```

Comment: Actually it does not just return `null`, but also raise a notice like "Notice: Undefined index: 'foo' in ... on line ...". So you should always make sure to use `isset` to check whether a value is present or not.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/) (*emphasis mine*):

> [**`$_GET`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php): An *associative array* of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

And here is what the [PHP Manual says about arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> **Note:** Attempting to access an array key which has not been defined is the same as accessing any other undefined variable: an **`E_NOTICE`**-level error message will be issued, and the result will be **`NULL`**.

But you could have found easily by just doing

```
var_dump($_GET['name']);
```

Comment: im new to php. Ill have to check out the var_dump method.

Comment: @giodamelio no problem. I suggest you go through the [Language Reference](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) to get a good overview of how PHP works. The manual is really invaluable and constantly updated. It should always be your first stop when having questions.

Answer (score 1):

It would return [NULL](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php).

To test if a variable isn't null you can use the [isset](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) method.

aka

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
if(isset($name)) echo "hello $name!";
```

Comment: Note that a variable can *exist* and return false from `isset()` as it returns false for NULL values, which is a valid value for a variable that exists.  Particularly important within arrays.  `$eg = array('a', NULL, 'b'); isset($eg[1]) == false; array_key_exists(1, $eg) == true;`

Comment: Irrelevant in this context, but I edited it for clarity prior to your comment anyway. :)